# Issue getting started with FullCalendar in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

For a reason or another, I really could not set up the FullCalendar.io for my ASP.Net Core project Razor Page. The documentation is also pretty poor imho so I will highly appreciate any tips on what I should do.

Firstly, I created the **CalendarController.cs**. The `View` that should show the calendar at this point is `Index` and I kept the controller method empty, like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The **Index.cshtml** is taken from here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />

    <link href='fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>

    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
        });

        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

If I run my project and go to `Calendar/Index`, the page is blank. What step did I miss? On the [getting started](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started#download) page, they state that a package has to be installed. The way I did was `Nu-Get Package Manager -> Install Jquery.FullCalendar` - is this the wrong way? I tried running this `npm install --save @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid` in the `Package Manager Console` but it didn't work out.

Any help regarding this is highly welcomed, as I said. Sorry for posting such a thing with all the documentation out there! I just couldn't figure it out coming from them.

EDIT: I also get the following warnings in the console:

> C:/Users/user/source/repos/Intersection/Intersection/Views/Calendar/fullcalendar/core/main.js' not found. and 'C:/Users/user/source/repos/Intersection/Intersection/Views/Calendar/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js' not found.

Comment: Do you see any javascript warnings or errors on the console?

Comment: @Marie Yes - `C:/Users/user/source/repos/Intersection/Intersection/Views/Calendar/fullcalendar/core/main.js' not found.` and `'C:/Users/user/source/repos/Intersection/Intersection/Views/Calendar/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js' not found.
`

Comment: I tried importing with drag & drop the archive `fullcalendar-4.3.1.zip` to `Views/Calendar` but I got the following errors: `Could not find module 'luxon'` and `Could not find module 'moment'`

Comment: According to the getting started page you linked in your question, when manually setting things up, `The first step is to download and unzip a ZIP archive from the Getting Started page` I dont know enough about .net core projects or razor page build pipelines to help further but your dependencies are definitely not setup correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```html
<link href='fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
```

I dont know wheres located your view, but in this instruction you are telling to look for the scripts in the same level as you are, which probably it is wrong; because you will have on the `wwwroot` folder, so something like should work, thats why it is telling you: "Couldnt file that file" , becasue theres no file in that location:

```html
<link href='~/fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='/wwwroot/yourPaht/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='~/wwwroot/yourPath/fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
```

Try that 4 ways and let us know!!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the JavaScript and CSS files for fullcalendar?  Seems like it's looking for them underneath the views folder here:

`/Views/Calendar/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js`

I'm guessing they are actually installed at the root of your project or under a `/content` or `/scripts` folder or something, so you'll need to update the `script` and `link` tags for your js and css files to point to the right place.

Comment: As I told @Marie: I tried importing with drag & drop the archive fullcalendar-4.3.1.zip to Views/Calendar but I got the following errors: Could not find module 'luxon' and Could not find module 'moment'. To be more precise - I did that ONLY with the package folder. EDIT: I put the whole content of the archive in the correct place but the `could not find module` errors keep persisting

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try to download [libary](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started#download)

put js file and css file to `~/content` or `~/script`